# create global socket object in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket, singleton

I am new to angular js and i have the requirement where i need to create single instance of socket object which can be accessed from any controller.

For this i created factory with private socket variable which connects to socket-io server automatically when application is started.
Also i created a public method to return that socket object.

I just want to know that whether this approach is fine or i can have a better solution for this.Also does this imply to create singleton object or not?
Below is the factory code i wrote for this purpose.
socketIOService.js

```
    (function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.core')
        /* @ngInject */
        .factory('ncSocketFactory', function(socketFactory, CALL_URL, $rootScope) {
            var socket  = io.connect(CALL_URL, {
                            transports: ["websocket"]
                        });


            socket.on('connect', function () {  
                console.log('socket io connected...');  
                $rootScope.$broadcast('socket:connected');
            });

            socket.on('incomingCall', function (data,evt) {  
                console.log('incomingCall data..'+data);
                $rootScope.incomingCallData = data;
                $rootScope.$broadcast('socket:incomingVideoCall');
            });



            socket.on('disconnect', function () {  
                console.log('socket io disconnected...');   
                $rootScope.$broadcast('socket:disconnected');
            });

            return {
                getSocketObject: function(){
                    return socket;
                },
                on: function (eventName, callback) {
                    socket.on(eventName, function () {                  
                  });
                },
                emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
                    socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                  });
                },
                reconnect: function () {
                    socket  = io.connect(CALL_URL, {
                        transports: ["websocket"]
                    });
                },
                disconnect: function () {
                    console.log('in socket disconnect:'+socket.connected);
                    if(socket.connected){
                        socket.disconnect();

                        console.log('ncSocketFactory disconnected');
                    }
                }
              };
        });
})();
```